# Jenkins Pipeline - how to javadoc a global pipeline library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, javadoc

Is there a way to run javadoc or the groovy equivalent against a global pipeline library? I out of habit wrote comments for every method that follow the javadoc format - would love if I could run javadoc against the library and have doc generated.

Comment: Are you talking about vars or Groovy classes in `src/`?

Comment: both vars and groovy classes in src/...

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), global variables (inside `vars/`) are documented in a `<name>.txt` file next to the `<name>.groovy` file.

Groovy classes within `src/` are.. well.. just Groovy code and thus [GroovyDoc](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_groovydoc_comment) should be used.

Comment: @user797963 did this help you? If yes, please use the checkmark on the left to mark this question as solved.

Comment: I wish there is a good automated solution like groovyDoc for vars. the standard *.txt available solution is just primitive IMHO

Comment: @YaP I'm not aware of anything